# Can't Edit CakePHP Website in Dreamweaver

Tags: cakephp, dreamweaver, edit, mamp

I just got done setting up my CakePHP website in MAMP and the databases and access files modified. Also, I went into Dreamweaver and modified it's configuration settings so it would open CTP files. In the browser, it's showing up properly. But, I can't get Dreamweaver to link properly, giving the error:

> Dynamically-related files could not be resolved because of an internal server error.

Is there something else specifically in Dreamweaver I should do?

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: I post this as a comment, because also it's true some people would downvote it: DO NOT!!!!!!! USE DREAMWEAVER.
Notepad++ is all you need. Or search for an IDE that supports like for example "Codelobster".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did as @func0der said and tried to find a nicer IDE that better supported CakePHP websites, and ended up going with Aptana and has worked pretty well so far.

Good luck to those wanting to edit their CakePHP website! :)